# plsql query throwing quoted string not terminated error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am unable to find the "quoted string not properly terminated" error in the below plsql which i am currently working on it ..

```
        set serverout ON feed OFF trimspool ON
        DECLARE
            t_cnt NUMBER;
            r_cnt NUMBER;
            tab_check BOOLEAN;
            iowner VARCHAR2(50);
            itable_name VARCHAR2(50);
            sql_query1 VARCHAR2(2000);
            sql_query2 VARCHAR2(2000);
            CpyCur SYS_REFCURSOR;
        BEGIN
            FUNCTION Istable_exist(Powner VARCHAR2,
            Ptable_name VARCHAR2)
            RETURN BOOLEAN
            AS
            tab_cnt NUMBER;
            BEGIN
              select count(1) into tab_cnt from dba_tables where table_name = 'SPLIT_EXT_INFO' and owner = 'dba';
              IF tab_cnt = 1 THEN
                RETURN TRUE;
              ELSE
                RETURN FALSE;
              END IF;
            END;

            FUNCTION get_split_qry
            RETURN VARCHAR
            AS
            sql_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
            BEGIN
            FOR x IN (SELECT split_mapper FROM dba.split_ext_info)
              LOOP
              sql_stmt := sql_stmt||' SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM dba.'||x.split_mapper||' where status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'') UNION ALL';
              END LOOP;
              sql_stmt := REGEXP_REPLACE(sql_stmt, ' UNION ALL$');
              --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_stmt);
              RERURN sql_stmt;
            END;

            SELECT Count(1)
            INTO   r_cnt
            FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner,
                                    src_table_name
                    FROM   dba.extent_map
                    WHERE  status = 'READY');

            tab_check := Istable_exist('dba','SPLIT_EXT_INFO');
            IF tab_check THEN
              split_qry := get_split_qry;
              sql_query1 := 'SELECT Trim(Count(1)) FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN ((SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) union all ('||split_qry||'))';
              sql_query2 := 'SELECT * FROM  (SELECT owner,table_name FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN ((SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) union all ('||split_qry||')) AND ( owner, table_name ) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map WHERE  status IN ( ''FAILCOPY'', ''READY''))  ORDER  BY dbms_random.value) WHERE  ROWNUM < 2';
            ELSE
              sql_query1 := 'SELECT Trim(Count(1)) FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY''));
              sql_query2 := 'SELECT * FROM  (SELECT owner,table_name FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) AND ( owner, table_name ) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map WHERE  status IN ( ''FAILCOPY'', ''READY''))  ORDER  BY dbms_random.value) WHERE  ROWNUM < 2';
            END IF;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query1);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query2);
            execute immediate sql_query1 into t_cnt;

            IF t_cnt = 0
               AND r_cnt = 0 THEN
              dbms_output.Put_line('NO_ACTION');
            ELSIF t_cnt = 0
                  AND r_cnt > 0 THEN
              dbms_output.Put_line('WAIT');
            ELSE
              OPEN CpyCur FOR sql_query2;
              LOOP
              FETCH  CpyCur INTO iowner, itable_name;
              EXIT WHEN CpyCur%NOTFOUND;
              dbms_output.Put_line(iowner
                                       ||':'
                                       ||itable_name);
              END LOOP;
            END IF;
        END;
        /
```

I am trying to query column "split_mapper" under split_ext_info table, then i am getting output based on ind_track table. then validating the output of it & then i am displaying the output.

Regards
kannan

Comment: If you even check the SO default formatting applied to your code, you'll easily find the answer. It is better not to use doubled quotes, use [alternative quoting syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) with `Q`

Comment: There is a typo: ```RERURN sql_stmt;```

Comment: Also you should debug your code and write it incrementally not to get surprises like this in the wall of code.

Comment: Thanks @astentx, quotes issue looks fixed now, but i am getting strange error related to Istableexist function ... am i missing anything here ?

Comment: ERROR at line 11:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 18:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ISTABLEEXIST" when expecting one of the
following:
:= . ( @ % ;

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/block.html#GUID-9ACEB9ED-567E-4E1A-A16A-B8B35214FC9D) about the structure of PL/SQL block. Declarations should be placed in `DECLARE` section

Comment: But i am declaring within the function properly right in that func "istableexist" am i missing anything ?

Comment: You need to declare your functions in the declaration section, not just anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're declaring functions within a PL/SQL procedure, then do so within its **declare** section, not in executable code. Also, `rerurn` should be replaced by `return`.

The following code *might* compile; can't test it, I don't have your tables.

```
DECLARE
   t_cnt        NUMBER;
   r_cnt        NUMBER;
   tab_check    BOOLEAN;
   iowner       VARCHAR2 (50);
   itable_name  VARCHAR2 (50);
   sql_query1   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   sql_query2   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   CpyCur       SYS_REFCURSOR;

   FUNCTION Istable_exist (Powner VARCHAR2, Ptable_name VARCHAR2)
      RETURN BOOLEAN
   AS
      tab_cnt  NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT (1)
        INTO tab_cnt
        FROM dba_tables
       WHERE     table_name = 'SPLIT_EXT_INFO'
             AND owner = 'dba';

      IF tab_cnt = 1
      THEN
         RETURN TRUE;
      ELSE
         RETURN FALSE;
      END IF;
   END;

   FUNCTION get_split_qry
      RETURN VARCHAR
   AS
      sql_stmt  VARCHAR2 (2000);
   BEGIN
      FOR x IN (SELECT split_mapper FROM dba.split_ext_info)
      LOOP
         sql_stmt :=
               sql_stmt
            || ' SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM dba.'
            || x.split_mapper
            || ' where status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'') UNION ALL';
      END LOOP;

      sql_stmt := REGEXP_REPLACE (sql_stmt, ' UNION ALL$');
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_stmt);
      RETURN sql_stmt;
   END;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO r_cnt
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name
             FROM dba.extent_map
            WHERE status = 'READY');

   tab_check := Istable_exist ('dba', 'SPLIT_EXT_INFO');

   IF tab_check
   THEN
      split_qry := get_split_qry;
      sql_query1 :=
            'SELECT Trim(Count(1)) FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN ((SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) union all ('
         || split_qry
         || '))';
      sql_query2 :=
            'SELECT * FROM  (SELECT owner,table_name FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN ((SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) union all ('
         || split_qry
         || ')) AND ( owner, table_name ) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map WHERE  status IN ( ''FAILCOPY'', ''READY''))  ORDER  BY dbms_random.value) WHERE  ROWNUM < 2';
   ELSE
      sql_query1 :=
         'SELECT Trim(Count(1)) FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY''))';
      sql_query2 :=
         'SELECT * FROM  (SELECT owner,table_name FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) AND ( owner, table_name ) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map WHERE  status IN ( ''FAILCOPY'', ''READY''))  ORDER  BY dbms_random.value) WHERE  ROWNUM < 2';
   END IF;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_query1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_query2);

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query1
      INTO t_cnt;

   IF     t_cnt = 0
      AND r_cnt = 0
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line ('NO_ACTION');
   ELSIF     t_cnt = 0
         AND r_cnt > 0
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line ('WAIT');
   ELSE
      OPEN CpyCur FOR sql_query2;

      LOOP
         FETCH CpyCur INTO iowner, itable_name;

         EXIT WHEN CpyCur%NOTFOUND;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line (iowner || ':' || itable_name);
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   set serverout ON feed OFF trimspool ON
    DECLARE
        t_cnt NUMBER;
        r_cnt NUMBER;
        tab_check BOOLEAN;
        iowner VARCHAR2(50);
        itable_name VARCHAR2(50);
        sql_query1 VARCHAR2(2000);
        sql_query2 VARCHAR2(2000);
        CpyCur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        FUNCTION Istable_exist(Powner VARCHAR2,
        Ptable_name VARCHAR2)
        RETURN BOOLEAN
        AS
        tab_cnt NUMBER;
        BEGIN
          select count(1) into tab_cnt from dba_tables where table_name = 'SPLIT_EXT_INFO' and owner = 'dba';
          IF tab_cnt = 1 THEN
            RETURN TRUE;
          ELSE
            RETURN FALSE;
          END IF;
        END;

        FUNCTION get_split_qry
        RETURN VARCHAR
        AS
        sql_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
        BEGIN
        FOR x IN (SELECT split_mapper FROM dba.split_ext_info)
          LOOP
          sql_stmt := sql_stmt||' SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM dba.'||x.split_mapper||' where status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'') UNION ALL';
          END LOOP;
          sql_stmt := REGEXP_REPLACE(sql_stmt, ' UNION ALL$');
          --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_stmt);
          RERURN sql_stmt;
        END;

        SELECT Count(1)
        INTO   r_cnt
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner,
                                src_table_name
                FROM   dba.extent_map
                WHERE  status = 'READY');

        tab_check := Istable_exist('dba','SPLIT_EXT_INFO');
        IF tab_check THEN
          split_qry := get_split_qry;
          sql_query1 := 'SELECT Trim(Count(1)) FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN ((SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) union all ('||split_qry||'))';
          sql_query2 := 'SELECT * FROM  (SELECT owner,table_name FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN ((SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) union all ('||split_qry||')) AND ( owner, table_name ) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map WHERE  status IN ( ''FAILCOPY'', ''READY''))  ORDER  BY dbms_random.value) WHERE  ROWNUM < 2';
        ELSE
          sql_query1 := 'SELECT Trim(Count(1)) FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY''))';
          sql_query2 := 'SELECT * FROM  (SELECT owner,table_name FROM   dba.ind_track WHERE  status = ''IND_DROP'' AND ( owner, table_name ) (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map  WHERE  status IN (''COPIED'', ''LOBMERGED'',''EMPTY'')) AND ( owner, table_name ) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT src_owner, src_table_name FROM   dba.extent_map WHERE  status IN ( ''FAILCOPY'', ''READY''))  ORDER  BY dbms_random.value) WHERE  ROWNUM < 2';
        END IF;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query1);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query2);
        execute immediate sql_query1 into t_cnt;

        IF t_cnt = 0
           AND r_cnt = 0 THEN
          dbms_output.Put_line('NO_ACTION');
        ELSIF t_cnt = 0
              AND r_cnt > 0 THEN
          dbms_output.Put_line('WAIT');
        ELSE
          OPEN CpyCur FOR sql_query2;
          LOOP
          FETCH  CpyCur INTO iowner, itable_name;
          EXIT WHEN CpyCur%NOTFOUND;
          dbms_output.Put_line(iowner
                                   ||':'
                                   ||itable_name);
          END LOOP;
        END IF;
    END;
    /
```

I believe line 53 was the issue where you define `sql_query1:=` on the `ELSE` branch

Comment: Thanks @gabriel durac, Now i am getting below error related to function, am i missing anything ? ERROR at line 11:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 18:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ISTABLEEXIST" when expecting one of the
following:
:= . ( @ % ;